# aspnet_regsql and deployment to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-authentication

I'm pretty new to Azure and trying to work on deploying an already existing MVC 3 website (I'm late to the project).

It has membership information (where the tables should be genned from aspnet_regsql) and it links those tables to application specific tables. To get it into a working state I need to insert some form of "default data" as the code does (unfortunately) make some assumptions about what should be in the database.

No bother, I have an app that creates a default database and inserts the required data. I can then import that into Azure, this doesn't work as Azure demands clustered indexes. This is because aspnet_regsql creates some auth table keys as unclustered so I'm now left having to alter these tables as part of the process to make the primary keys clustered.

I was just wondering if aspnet_regsql had been superceded somehow due to Azure demanding clustered indexes? Am I missing a trick here or is writing a script to modify the clustering of these indexes the sensible approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution elsewhere here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2006191/de

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Universal Providers, you don't need the scripts.

Check out [Hanselman's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx). The Universal providers will manage the database creation if you are working with SQL Server, Compact Edition, or Windows Azure Database

There are a lot of references to updated scripts including some on my own blog that are no longer needed.

Comment: Had originally deleted this since the OP mentioned it was an existing site. But if anyone is searching in the future, they should use the Universal Providers going forward

Comment: Had problems with providers in Azure, this blog post is excellent. All working with no code changes. Universal Providers are the way to go, thanks Dennis. Working in 2016.